# Fast search for the longest repeating substrings in large text

Tags: c++, strings, search

Is there a chance to implement the code below better with the features of recent C++ versions?

**Functional specification**

Having a large text and already built prefix array find the longest substrings (limited by the number of repetitions) getting benefit from already existing prefix array, if reasonable. Provide the version which would benefit from multi-threading keeping the code as simple as possible.

**Implementation**

The fully functional [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zYWGfv87f).

*Reservation: current implementation utilizes execution policies, so using ranges/projections/views under the question; would work if multi-threading requirement from above met.*

The code has raised my question on SO [Is there a way to introduce transparent sentinels before the begin and at the end of std::vector data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77815543/is-there-a-way-to-introduce-transparent-sentinels-before-the-begin-and-at-the-en), where I tried to simplify array borders checking guards, introducing sentinels and people answered that here we need to simplify the code first to see if this ever needed. So, I publish the code to see if this code could be written much simpler before trying sentinels.

Most important pieces of code under the question are below.

**Helper function** to simplify the core search function:

```cpp
std::size_t findMatchLength(const char* text, std::size_t index1, std::size_t index2) {
    // Limit the offset so we do not read past the beginning of the array.
    auto limit = std::min(index1, index2);
    for (std::size_t offset = 0; offset <= limit; ++offset)
        if (text[index1 - offset] != text[index2 - offset])
            return offset;

    return limit + 1;
}
```

As a second thought, I am in two minds about the **findMatchLength** function. It works pretty well to simplify the **findLongestSimilarSequences** function and self-documenting its flow, but violates Occam's razor principle, introducing a new essence. When I figured out the name for it, I based on the usage context in the **findLongestSimilarSequences** function. On the other hand, I can't explain its existence in higher scope, namely I can't give it a good generic name which explains what exactly it does and can't explain usage of both indexes out of context of **findLongestSimilarSequences**. So, from this perspective, this is a bad candidate for extraction and generalization. Please, correct me if I am wrong here.

Another **helper function template** to update maximum value in multi-threading environment.

```
template<typename T>
void update_max(std::atomic<T>& max_value, T const& value) noexcept
{
    T prev_value = max_value;
    while (prev_value < value && 
           !max_value.compare_exchange_weak(prev_value, value))
    {}
}
```

The **search function** itself:

```
void findLongestSimilarSequences(std::string& text, const std::vector<int>& index) {
    constexpr std::size_t largest_sequence = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max();
    const int max_repetitions = 5; // Could be replaced with smallest sequence to find

    std::vector <std::size_t> adjacent_matches(index.size());

    for (int repetitions = 2; repetitions <= max_repetitions; ++repetitions) {
        std::atomic<std::size_t> max_match_length = 0;
        std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, index.begin(), index.end() - (repetitions - 1), [&](const int& item) {
            size_t idx = &item - std::data(index);

            std::size_t match_length = findMatchLength(text.c_str(), item, *(&item + (repetitions-1)));

            adjacent_matches[idx] = match_length;

            if (match_length < largest_sequence) {
                update_max(max_match_length, match_length);
            }
        });

        if (max_match_length < 1)
            continue;

        std::cout << "Longest equal sequence(s) repeated " << repetitions << " times is " << max_match_length << " chars" << std::endl;

        std::cout << "The susequence(s) are:" << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < adjacent_matches.size()-1; ++i) {
            if (adjacent_matches[i] == max_match_length) {
                std::cout << text.substr(index[i] - (max_match_length - 1),max_match_length) << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Concerns for this function**

1. I don’t like the code structure, is there a way to simplify it and make more readable?
2. I don’t like two responsibilities of the function, namely *to find substrings* and *to print them*, but I don’t see better solutions (maybe callback for printing?) because the text size is large and there could be too many results to keep them in maps and other dynamic structures which will cause significant memory fragmentation and could be time-consuming.
3. Some other questions are in form of comments in the code.

The **main** function is quite simple:

```
int main()
{
    std::string text = "This-string-contains-repetitions-and-these-repetitions-the-string-contains-as-repetitions-these-repetitions";
    
    // Am I correct that this wouldn't create a copy of array on return from function?
    // Will copy elision do its work or should I do something explicit?
    auto prefix_array_index = buildPrefixArrayIndex(text); 

    findLongestSimilarSequences(text, prefix_array_index);
}
```

Please don’t pay much attention to using std::string and its functions here, in the real code the text is compiled in lexems ids and stored in `std::vector<int>`, but this implementation would grow the code size here which I want to avoid.

Please don’t pay much attention to the function **buildPrefixArrayIndex**, as well, since it is provided only to make the code executable and testable. In real code it is based on `std::vector` and offsets.

```
std::vector<int> buildPrefixArrayIndex(const std::string& str) {
    std::vector<int> suffix_array(str.length());
    std::iota(suffix_array.begin(), suffix_array.end(), 0);

    std::sort(std::execution::par_unseq, suffix_array.begin(), suffix_array.end(), [&](int lhs, int rhs) {
    auto lstr = str.substr(0, lhs + 1);
        // Could be replaced with rbegin(), but I am not sure that code will be readable
        std::reverse(lstr.begin(),lstr.end());

        auto rstr = str.substr(0,rhs+1);
        std::reverse(rstr.begin(), rstr.end());

        return lstr < rstr;
        });

    return suffix_array;
}
```

Can you please conduct code review and show the way to implement this code with the latest versions of C++?
I want to keep with pure C++ without any libraries like boost (of course, STL is applicable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Redesign the interface

You already have some doubts about your code's structure, in particular that `findLongestSimilarSequences()` has too many responsibilities. You want the function to just do the finding part, and move the loop that prints the longest sequences out of it. So ideally, you want to be able to write something like:

```
for (int repetitions = 2; repetitions <= 5; ++repetitions) {
    std::cout << "Longest equal sequence(s) repeated " << repetitions << " times:\n";
    for (auto sequence: findLongestSimilarSequences(text, index, repetitions)) {
        std::cout << sequence << "\n";
    }
}
```

So `findLongestSimilarSequences()` has to return something that can be iterated over. That can be as simple as a `std::vector<std::string_view>`, which is quite efficient. Consider that you already allocate a vector of size `index.size()` in your function.

```
std::vector<std::string_view>
findLongestSimilarSequences(const std::string& text,
                            const std::vector<int>& index,
                            int min_repetitions)
{
    // Build adjacent_matches
    …

    // Create the result
    std::vector<std::string_view> result;

    for (int i = 0; i < adjacent_matches.size() - 1; ++i) {
        if (adjacent_matches[i] == max_match_length) {
            result.emplace_back(text.data() + index[i] - (max_match_length - 1), max_match_length);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

But when looking at your code, I also have other questions about the interface:

- Why is your `text` not passed as a `const` reference?
- Why not use [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) for `text`?
- Why limit it to strings at all? It seems to me that you could make this work for any kind of range.
- Why does the caller need to pass a vector named `index`? What if you pass the wrong "index"? Either let `findLongestSimilarSequences` calculate this index, or create a `class` that encapsulates both the text and index, and pass a reference to that to this function.
- Why does the name say "SimilarSequences"? That implies they might not be exactly identical. I think "RepeatedSubsequences" would be a better name.

## Keep code simple and clear

I had to read `findMatchLength()` a few times to understand why it works, as normally I would expect a function like this to compare to substrings in the *forward* direction. I guess it's smart to pass indices to the end of the substrings, so you can use the minimum of those to avoid out-of-bounds reads, and in *this particular* use case you don't care about finding the match length of the strings reversed.

A much more intuitive interface would be to just pass two substrings, and compare them forwards. Then you can also use STL algorithms such as [`std::mismatch()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch), or even better, its [ranges version](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/mismatch):

```
std::size_t findMatchLength(std::string_view str1, std::string_view str2) {
    return std::ranges::mismatch(str1, str2).in1 - str1.begin();
}
```

## The standard library might get an atomic max function

There have been [proposals](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0493r1.pdf) to get atomic max and min functions into the standard library. While your `update_max()` looks fine, consider renaming it and changing the interface to the proposed `atomic_fetch_max()`, which will have an interface very similar to [`std::atomic_fetch_add()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_fetch_add). This would make refactoring your code later to make use of a standard function simpler.

```
template<typename T>
T atomic_fetch_max(std::atomic<T>* obj, typename std::atomic<T>::value_type arg) noexcept
{
    auto prev = obj->load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    while (prev < arg && !obj->compare_exchange_weak(prev, arg)) {}
    return prev;
}
```

## Your code can return duplicates

Try adding a dash at the end of your test string in `main()`. Your code doesn't find subsequences with an exact number of repetitions, but rather with a minimum number of repetitions. And when the actual number of repetitions found is larger than the minimum number of repetitions, it will print the same subsequence multiple times.

## Other issues

- [Use `"\n"` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually unnecessary and has a negative impact on performance.
- You use `int` in some places to hold sizes, like the loop iterator `i` and as the value type of the vector `index`. If the text is larger than can be represented by an `int`, your code will no longer work correctly. Always prefer to use [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) for sizes, counts and indices.
- You can avoid the atomic variable by changing the `for_each()` into a [`transform_reduce()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce). However, it probably doesn't improve performance in a significant way.

Comment: `auto prev = *obj;` [won't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77851234/cant-compile-suggested-atomic-fetch-max-code) (`*obj` is a `std::atomic<T>` so `auto` picks that, not `T`, and the deleted copy-constructor saves us from compiling with an atomic local var).  You want `auto prev = obj->load(std::memory_order_relaxed);` which produces a `T`.

Comment: Is there any advantage to `typename std::atomic<T>::value_type arg` over just `T` in the args?  (And which doesn't apply to the return value where you just used `T`?)  I see that prototype is just copied from P0493R1; they don't mention a motivation for `value_type`.  ([Damir also asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77851234/cant-compile-suggested-atomic-fetch-max-code) why not `T const &`, but that has an easy answer: `T` should be small for lock-free atomics, probably at most `long long` or `double` for max to make sense, so can be passed more efficiently by value than by reference.)

Comment: I just did this indeed to exactly copy the way the proposal and already standardized atomic operations are declared. The standard also says `value_type` should be equal to `T`, so indeed it seems very unnecessary. Maybe this is a good question for StackOverflow?

Comment: [What happened to std::atomic::value\_type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53648614) sheds some light on the change from `T` to `...::value_type` -  https://wg21.link/P0558R1 fixed an apparent defect.  I haven't waded through the details.

Comment: If I read P0558R1 correctly, it seems to be to help with type deduction when you call the atomic function with a value of a different type than `T`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. I will compile most of the answers in form of a new version of code for the next code review iteration and will be thankful if you could continue the code review and suggestions. Let me address all other points (where I have answers or counter questions) one by one (since the length is limited) in form of comments.

Comment: (1) I am not sure that interface redesign with function extraction is the best solution, since it causes at least two problems (a) I won’t have a proper place to report about length of the sequences found (I will show it in the new version of code); (b) allocating a new vector for results leads to memory allocation/releasing and, possibly, fragmentation.  I am not sure that new dynamic structure is a reasonable pay for this decoupling. Let’s discuss in the new version of code.

Comment: (2) The `text` was not passed by a `const` reference just by a misprint. Fixed, of course.
(3) I am not sure where you meant to use `std::string_view` in my original code before you made function extraction. Anyway, the key reason is that as I stated in my question “*Please don’t pay much attention to using std::string and its functions here, in the real code the text is compiled in lexems ids and stored in std::vector<int>, but this implementation would grow the code size here which I want to avoid.*”

Comment: (4) I limit this code to strings because I don’t want to make it template based which will force me to put it in header files, breaking insulation and increasing compilation time. If you mean some way to make is working for any range without making them template and keeping them in C++ implementation files, please give me clue.

Comment: (5) On the putting together text and index, in the real code I do this, my idea was to not overcomplicate the demo code, keeping the focus on algorithm and code structure. At the same time, closing eyes on simple and straightforward way to put text and index together, this is not a simple task, as my question [The best place to store index to data]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77808469/the-best-place-to-store-index-to-data) shown; people even suggest to use database for this simple task. :)

Comment: (6) I agree that RepeatedSubsequences work better here, point taken, thank you. (This is the “copy legacy” from my original code where the real function compares categories which results in similar sentences).
(7) The `findMatchLength` could have worked in forward direction if I had *array of suffixes*, unfortunately, I have the *array of prefixes*, which forces me to find backwards. I believe, this could be easily solved with use of reverse iterators, but for sake of example, let’s assume in the next versions that I have array of suffixes and keep code searching forward.

Comment: (8) **Code can return duplicates** is the hardest part both from code and functional specification. Thank you so much for catching this (by the way, what kind of action led you to find this?). The problem is that I am not sure what result I want to see if some line repeated N times; should I report it as reported N-k times, as well, or should I report lines which repeated *only* N times and not more. I will focus on this at the next version of code. I am still in two minds here how generic function should handle this.

Comment: (9) The `“\n”` vs `std::endl`. I see where you coming from and I wouldn’t argue here, accepting the change. Just to explain my background. When program crashes I’d like to have all messages in my log files, not losing the write cache, so I am used to put `std::endl`; well, not always this is the point to care. On the other hand here you care about some flushes of output and above in (1) you are ready to allocate/release vector to extract dozen lines of code. Are you sure that this is consistent?

Comment: (10)  On the use `size_t` instead of `int`, agree for most cases, thank you. One reservation for the current task, using it for vector `index` will double the size of the vector which is not my option at the moment, since on test runs the `index` size is less than 4Gb, so for a moment I decided to use my `index_t` type for it to be able to replace it with `using` directive, will be in the new version of the code.

Comment: I posted the update revision of the code under the [Rev.2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289063/fast-search-for-the-longest-repeating-substrings-in-large-text-rev-2) code review request. Could you please, take a look? Can the code be improved?