# Fast search for the longest repeating substrings in large text (Rev.3)

Tags: c++, strings, search

This is the third iteration of the [Fast search for the longest repeating substrings in large text (Rev.2)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289063/fast-search-for-the-longest-repeating-substrings-in-large-text-rev-2) code review. Special thanks goes to G. Sliepen who conducted the first two reviews.

**Functional specification**

Having a large text and already built suffix array find the longest substrings (limited by the number of repetitions) getting benefit from already existing prefix array, if reasonable. Provide the version which would benefit from multithreading keeping the code as simple as possible.

**Implementation**

The fully functional [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vq6q558ao).

*Reservation: current implementation utilizes execution policies, so using ranges/projections/views under the question; would work if multi-threading requirement from above met.*
The further details make sense only as addition to aforementioned second Code Review with answer to it.

**Answers to the questions on previous revision code review**

1. On the dilemma “this number or more” or “exactly this number” it is really funny. I tested both on real texts and real environment they give much the same results; the difference is subtle. Main goal was to clean up text base from text duplicates (like the same story in different collections of works, etc.). Even more, the same goes to duplication defect from the first version. With this I mean that all defects, of course, must be fixed and option for different way of search should be provided, but in real environment even “slightly erroneous version” is “good enough”. Just funny side note.
2. I tested both versions of **calculateAdjacents** with `std::for_each` and with `std::transform_reduce` on real data. You are correct, no significant difference in performance, which is highly reasonable, but since I am aiming to port this to GPU with many cores later, I decided to stay with `std::transform_reduce` which should give some speed up on GPU, I believe.

Here is the current implementation of *calculateAdjacents*:

```
// Returns found sequence(s) length
size_t calculateAdjacents(const Index<>& index,
                          std::vector<index_t>& adjacent_matches,
                          size_t repetitions,
                          bool strong_repetition_count)
{
    std::fill(std::execution::par_unseq, adjacent_matches.begin(), adjacent_matches.end(), 0);

    size_t max_match_length = std::transform_reduce(/*std::execution::par_unseq,*/
        index.begin(), index.end() - (repetitions - 1), size_t(0), 
        [&](size_t max_match_length, size_t match_length) -> size_t {
            return std::max(max_match_length, match_length);
        }, 
        [&](const auto& item) -> size_t {
            const auto& text = index.text;
            size_t idx = &item - std::data(index.index);
            
            size_t match_length = findMatchLengthWithOffsetInSuffixArray(index, idx, (repetitions - 1));

            if (strong_repetition_count) {
                // Not more than min_repetitions times before item
                if (&item > std::data(index.index)) {
                    size_t prev_match_length = findMatchLengthWithOffsetInSuffixArray(index, idx, -1);

                    if (prev_match_length == match_length)
                        return 0;
                }

                // Not more than min_repetitions times after (item+repetitions-1)
                if ((size_t)((&item + repetitions) - std::data(index.index)) < index.size()) {
                    size_t next_match_length = findMatchLengthWithOffsetInSuffixArray(index, idx, repetitions);

                    if (next_match_length == match_length)
                        return 0;
                }
            }

            adjacent_matches[idx] = (index_t)match_length;

            return match_length;
        });

    return max_match_length;
}
```

3. On keeping the *findMatchLength*, this is kind of adherence to Occam's razor principle to avoid unnecessary entities and a kind of rule of thumb like “If you can’t explain in simple words (preferably by function name) what it does generically, out of context of current task, avoid creating it or at least avoid making it visible to client. For this particular function I can’t explain in simple words what it does without this task context.
4. On the “I would be happy to avoid this `std::fill' at the beginning of *calculateAdjacents* function, but I am not sure if this is possible.”, I most likely wrongly worded my intention. I mean I want to avoid clearing the vector this way or another. I am not concerned with the way it is done, I am concerned with the algorithm which requires it and I am looking for a way to avoid such performance-consuming operation with high memory-bounding. I will do my best to change the algorithm to avoid this in the subsequent versions. At the same time, I don’t want to move it to *calculateAdjacents*, because this will cause allocating and releasing this array on each function call. Taking into account that its size equal to text size, on large text bases this could be quite expensive; this is the reason I create the array on a higher level.
5. In real code I wouldn't use std::string and will use std::vector to keep identifiers (unsigned int) of lexems (actually, even a bit deeper – identifiers of categories or clusters of lexem, but this doesn’t matter at the moment). That’s why in the next revision I will move from std::string to std::vector just to better understand how to manipulate with sequences in absence of std::string and std::string_view functions.

**Major changes**

1. Since in real project I will use lexem identifiers instead of plain text, I did some “emulation” in code for this, making pseudo tokenizer which for the sake of simplicity just converts characters’ codes to ints. This is just a trick to go to real types I use and move from std::string and std::string_views. Another step to make algorithm generic, meanwhile.

So, I introduced the:

```
using lexem_t = unsigned int;
using index_t = unsigned int;
```

2. Function parameters *text* and *index* replaced with *Index* template which will be covered below.
3. “Subtle” defect for the "this number or more" version (“weak count”) mentioned by *G. Sliepen* has been fixed in the *collectRepeatingSubstrings* function.
4. The *max_repetitions* threshold removed; it is not needed even on large data sets, no significant performance impact or memory footprint on real data.
5. The *collectRepeatingSubstrings* function reworked according recommendations. New version is much more readable.

Here it is:

```
struct SubstringOccurences {
    std::span<const lexem_t> sequence;
    std::vector<index_t> pos;
};

std::vector<SubstringOccurences>
collectRepeatingSubstrings(const Index<>& index,
    std::vector<index_t> adjacent_matches,
    size_t repetitions,
    size_t max_match_length)
{
    std::vector<SubstringOccurences> result;

    size_t j = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < adjacent_matches.size() - 1; i+=j) {
        if (adjacent_matches[i] == max_match_length) {
            result.emplace_back(
                std::span(index.text.begin() + index[i], max_match_length),
                std::vector(&index[i], &index[i + repetitions])
            );
        }

        for (j = 1; i+j < adjacent_matches.size() 
                    && max_match_length == findMatchLengthWithOffsetInSuffixArray(index, i, j); ++j)
            ;
    }

    return result;
}
```

6. The *findMatchLength* function inlined to *findMatchLengthWithOffsetInSuffixArray* to avoid swamping the namespace.

Here is how it looks like now:

```
size_t findMatchLengthWithOffsetInSuffixArray(const Index<>& index, 
                                              const size_t idx,
                                              ptrdiff_t offset)
{
    const auto& text = index.text;

    return std::mismatch(text.begin() + index[idx], text.end(), 
                         text.begin() + index[idx + offset], text.end()).first 
                       - (text.begin() + index[idx]);
}
```

7. Introduced option *strong_repetition_count* to control the way the algorithm handles repetitions parameter: “find substring with exact number of repetitions” = “strong count” and “find substring with this number of repetitions or more” = “weak count”.

**My concerns on this code**

1. I started with a dozen lines of code and now it grew to 150+ lines of code most of which is still not reusable. I had one function, now I have 2 new types and 4 functions. Well, some defects were fixed which complicated the code a bit, but mostly I paid for functional decomposition. I am still in two minds that the price is reasonable. Anyway, this is still not a final version, so, let’s compare the final result.
2. While the function *findRepeatedSubsequences* is a kind of client function, I don’t like that std::cout (or any other stream) is build-in here. Of course, I can return new object *RepeatedSubsequences* from this function which will collect all the results and overload the operator << for this type in order to be able to output it in any stream in usual manner, but this will additionally complicate the code and will have performance and memory footprint on storing these results.

Here is how the functions looks like now:

```
void findRepeatedSubsequences(const Index<>& index, size_t max_repetitions, bool strong_repetition_count = true)
{
    std::vector<index_t> adjacent_matches(index.size());

    for (size_t repetitions = 2 ; repetitions <= max_repetitions; ++repetitions) {
        size_t sequence_length = calculateAdjacents(index, adjacent_matches, repetitions, strong_repetition_count);

        if (sequence_length < 1)
            continue;

        std::cout << "Longest equal sequence(s) repeated " << repetitions << " times is " << sequence_length << " chars.\n";

        for (auto sequence : collectRepeatingSubstrings(index, adjacent_matches, repetitions, sequence_length)) {
            std::cout << "The sequence at position(s): (";

            const char* delimiter = "";
            for (auto pos : sequence.pos) {
                std::cout << delimiter << pos;
                delimiter = ",";
            }
            std::cout << "): ";

            std::copy(sequence.sequence.begin(), sequence.sequence.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
            
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

**Index class**

I had a special homework from *G. Sliepen* to figure out the name for the structure to wrap up references to text and index.

My way of thinking is following:

1. I really need only the index and it would be nice if reference to text is stored somehow in it.
2. It would be nice to have this index type transparent for the client code in order to avoid client code like index.index as much as possible. (I still have it in `std::data(index.index)`, which could easily be replaced with `index.begin()` in this context, but I eager to learn how to handle this case, as well.

Before these code reviews I raised the question [The best place to store index to data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77808469/the-best-place-to-store-index-to-data) where I didn’t get better proposals than my way to wrap up the references to index and indexed text into Index structure:

```
template <typename LexemType=lexem_t, typename IndexType = index_t>
struct Index {
    const std::vector<LexemType>& text;
    const std::vector<IndexType>& index;
public:
    decltype(index.begin()) begin() const { return index.begin(); }
    decltype(index.end())   end() const { return index.end(); }

    size_t size() const { return index.size(); }
    const IndexType& operator[] (size_t idx) const { return index[idx]; }
};
```

*Some reservations: I made it a structure to avoid excessive accessors. I don’t think they would help much here. Of course, having text and index public makes redundant exposing begin(), end(), size() and operator[]; I made it to simplify client code.*

**Other code snippets**

Since I moved from std::string to std::vector to keep the sequences, I reworked *SubstringOccurences* to:

```
struct SubstringOccurences {
    std::span<const lexem_t> sequence;
    std::vector<index_t> pos;
};
```

I hope, this is the correct way and place to use `std::span`.

**Generalization**

One of the questions from *G. Sliepen* was *“Why limit it to strings at all? It seems to me that you could make this work for any kind of range.”*.

The only reason I am keeping this not generic is that I want to keep implementation in source files, not in headers in order to maximize insulation (physical encapsulation), reduce compile time and keep visible interfaces free of utility functions.

If there is a way to make them generic without exposing them to header files, it would be nice to know. If not and it goes to header files, there is another question. The *findMatchLengthWithOffsetInSuffixArray* is not generic, I can’t explain to user what it does without the context of the task, as well as *calculateAdjacents* and *collectRepeatingSubstrings*. What is the best way to hide them from client? Create nested utility namespace? Wrap up everything in class which will be able to hold the results and support operator << and will provide encapsulation? Other methods?

Is there any way to improve this code? Any mistakes or issues? Could you please help conducting further steps of code review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Don't use `decltype()` unnecessarily

In `Index` you have this member functions:

```
decltype(index.begin()) begin() const { return index.begin(); }
```

First of all, you are repeating `index.begin()` twice. What if the body of your `begin()` is much more complicated? It quickly becomes very complicated to declare the return type like that. You could just use `decltype(auto)`. However, why do you need `decltype()` at all here? It would only make sense if you were forwarding the return value of a function whose return type you don't know. But here it is clear: `index.begin()` returns an iterator *by value*. It wouldn't ever make sense for it to return a reference. So just write:

```
auto begin() const { return index.begin(); }
```

## Be consistent

If you are using return type deduction for `begin()` and `end()` in `Index`, why not use the same for `size()` and `operator[]()`?

If you make `Index` a template so you can vary `LexemType` and `IndexType`, why isn't `SubstringOccurences` a template in the same way? And why are `calculateAdjacents()` and the other functions that take an index as input templates? Either nothing should be a template here, or everything should.

## `index` and `text` are not `private`

In `struct Index`, nothing is `private`. You added the member functions `begin()`, `end()`, `size()` and `operator[]()` to avoid other code from directly accessing the member variables. But other code is accessing those member functions directly anyway.

Again, be consistent: either just make it a simple struct that is just holding two vectors without member functions, or make it a `class` that makes all member variables `private` and only allows access via member functions.

## Clearing `adjacent_matches`

Inside the call to `std::transform_reduce()` you only ever write to `adjacent_matches`. You visit every index from the start to the end minus `repetitions - 1`. So if you ensure you *always* write to `adjacent_matches[idx]` in the transformation function, then the only thing left to do afterwards is to clear the last `repetitions - 1` elements.

## Remove responsibilities from `findRepeatedSubsequences()`

> While the function *findRepeatedSubsequences* is a kind of client function, I don’t like that std::cout (or any other stream) is build-in here.

Indeed, that's bad. This function is now responsible both for finding repeated subsequences (as its name implies), and for formatting the result and printing it to `std::cout`. It should just do the former.

> Of course, I can return new object *RepeatedSubsequences* from this function which will collect all the results

That's not an unreasonable way to do it.

> and overload the operator << for this type in order to be able to output it in any stream in usual manner,

No. Again, this unnecessarily complicates `RepeatedSubsequences`. What if you don't want to output the result to a stream, but do something else with it? Or what if I want to be able to format the output as JSON or XML instead of printing something human readable? You can't just add more and more member functions to that class just to cover all possible uses. It might never end. Just make sure other code can access the results stored in it.

> [this] will have performance and memory footprint on storing these results.

That is a valid concern. There are various ways to go about this. First, I would remove the loop from `findRepeatedSubsequences()`, so it only finds repeated subsequences for one value of `repetitions`. If you are worried about repeated allocation and initialization of `adjacent_matches`, you can make it a `static` variable:

```
RepeatedSubsequences
findRepeatedSubsequences(const Index<>& index, size_t repetitions,
                         bool strong_repetition_count = true)
{
    static std::vector<index_t> adjacent_matches;
    adjacent_matches.resize(index.size());

    RepeatedSubsequences result;

    result.sequence_length =
        calculateAdjacents(index, adjacent_matches, repetitions,
                           strong_repetition_count);
    result.repeating_substrings =
        collectRepeatingSubstrings(index, adjacent_matches, repetitions,
                                   result.sequence_length));

    return result;
}
```

Now you can create a `printRepeatedSubsequences()` function that formats the contents of a `RepeatedSubsequences` object.

Another option is to keep the outer `for`-loop in `findRepeatedSubsequences()`, but pass a callback function to it that will be called for every iteration:

```
template<typename Callback>
void findRepeatedSubsequences(const Index<>& index, size_t max_repetitions,
                              bool strong_repetition_count = true,
                              Callback callback)
{
    std::vector<index_t> adjacent_matches(index.size());

    for (size_t repetitions = 2 ; repetitions <= max_repetitions; ++repetitions) {
        RepeatedSubsequences result;

        result.sequence_length =
            calculateAdjacents(index, adjacent_matches, repetitions,
                               strong_repetition_count);

        if (sequence_length < 1)
            continue;

        result.repeating_substrings =
            collectRepeatingSubstrings(index, adjacent_matches, repetitions,
                                       sequence_length);

        callback(result);
    }
}
```

The caller can then pass `printRepeatedSubsequences()` as the callback function, or whatever else it likes. But I think it is more complicated than necessary in this case.

## About the code size

> I started with a dozen lines of code and now it grew to 150+ lines of code most of which is still not reusable.

The code from the first revision you posted here was more than two dozen lines of code, even excluding `buildPrefixArrayIndex()`. Some of the growth comes from nicer formatting of the output, and from fixing some of the bugs you had in the first version.

> I had one function, now I have 2 new types and 4 functions. Well, some defects were fixed which complicated the code a bit, but mostly I paid for functional decomposition.

But that's fine. Splitting code into multiple functions usually makes it easier to read, more maintainable and more self-documenting. This is well worth the extra number of lines.

The biggest increase in code size comes from `calculateAdjacents()`, and in particular to support the `strong_repetition_count`. I would focus on simplifying this function. Consider:

```
size_t calculateAdjacents(const Index<>& index,
                          std::vector<index_t>& adjacent_matches,
                          size_t repetitions,
                          bool strong_repetition_count)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(/*std::execution::par_unseq,*/
                                 index.begin(),
                                 index.end() - (repetitions - 1), size_t(0),
                                 std::ranges::max,
                                 [&](const auto& item) -> size_t {
        const auto& text = index.text;
        size_t idx = &item - std::data(index.index);
            
        size_t match_length = findMatchLengthWithOffsetInSuffixArray(index, idx, (repetitions - 1));

        if (strong_repetition_count && !isStrongRepetition(match_length, …))
            match_length = 0;
        }

        return adjacent_matches[idx] = match_length;
    });
}
```

Sure, I moved the problem to `isStrongRepetition()`. But now that problem is compartmentalized and `calculateAdjacents()` looks reasonably simple again.

Comment: On the "index and text are not private", didn't my text "*Some reservations: I made it a structure to avoid excessive accessors. I don’t think they would help much here. Of course, having text and index public makes redundant exposing begin(), end(), size() and operator[]; I made it to simplify client code.*" cover my intentions? I wanted to simplify client code. Anyway, I'd love to make them private if I could solve the issue with 'std::data(index)` which requires the container. Can you give advice here?

Comment: Sure, why not add a `data()` member function that returns `index.data()`? My main issue is that you are not being *consistent*. If you want to simplify client code by not having to make it access `index.index`, then just make it so it *never* has to do that. In your code some operations are simplified, others are not.

Comment: This works, thanks. I was just used to 'std::data' instead of 'obj.data()' to be able to handle pure C++ arrays if necessary. It seems that in this case this is excessive, since I anyway stuck to `Index` interface which will handle this.

Comment: The main thing about `Index` structure/class you didn't touch in this round of code review, it was my homework to develop the name for it (and the approach itself). Are you agree with the solution for 'Index` or you had different or better ways to do this?

Comment: Thank you again for your time and help here. I reworked the code according to your recommendations in posted in [Fast search for the longest repeating substrings in large text (Rev.4)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289260/fast-search-for-the-longest-repeating-substrings-in-large-text-rev-4). It seems that we are close to have it done, but I still have some comments, questions and doubts. Could you please revisit the new version?